# Push down the rest of the page when form drops down

Tags: html, css, css-float

How do I push down a page's content when I click on a header button that should drop down a form?

Comment: Can you be more specific or give an example or ideally a fiddle? Your question is a little ambiguous.

Comment: What does your current code look like? When you tried to implement this yourself, how did it notwork as you expected?

Comment: what I have at the moment slides over the content below....I'm using twitter bootstrap's search form...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9rCcn/

Comment: I basically have the same code as you have...but when I click on the link it drop down the form over the content below. I dont know if it has to do with twitter bootstrap because I'm using its default search form.

Answer (score 0):

if you have position your DOM well, it should be push down automatically. 
please check the float style for your content to make sure they are on the same float level; then add overlow:auto to the from you just drop down to make sure the container of the form put up to its content's height.  it should work fine.

Comment: Hi Peng, what do you mean by position your DOM well?